# how to add new line at the end with awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk, printf, newline

I was searching and trying a lot of different approaches, but non of them really did what I need.
Hopefully it was not asked million times before.

I have this alias in my bashrc:

```
alias temp='awk '\''{ printf ("%0.1f",$1/1000); }'\'' < /sys/devices/platform/sunxi-i2c.0/i2c-0/0-0034/temp1_input'
```

output of it is:

```
measure@remote ~ $ temp
10.6measure@remote ~ $
```

what I'm trying to achieve is ouput like this:

```
measure@remote ~ $ temp
10.6
measure@remote ~ $
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace

```
"%0.1f"
```

with

```
"%0.1f\n"
```

Answer (score 5):

Generic answer to *how to add new line at the end with awk* would be:

```
$ awk '... END{print "\n"}'  # or print ORS
```

Comment: @EdMorton I stand corrected. I'll leave this unedited for a while for self shaming on not thinking it through before posting (then again, it _adds a new line ..._).

Answer (score 3):

Never use an alias for substituting a command and especially ones involving nested quotes like this. Just use a function in `.bashrc` to simplify it

```
get_ratio() {
    awk '{ printf ("%0.1f\n",$1/1000); }' /sys/devices/platform/sunxi-i2c.0/i2c-0/0-0034/temp1_input
}
```

and call it from the command line

```
measure@remote ~ $ source ~/.bashrc
measure@remote ~ $ get_ratio
```